# how to fit textbox in the table cell

Tags: asp.net, html, css

.. been trying to fit the textbox (auto adjust the textbox width) within HTML table's cell but no luck.. can anyone please help? thanks

What I have:

```
<td>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" style="width:100%"/>
</td>
```

Comment: <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" style="width:100%"/></td>

Comment: It says in your code you're using ASP also. You should state this when asking questions, and add it into your tags.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks - would it make a diff?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Textboxes" like `<textarea>` are inline elements. You need to make this:

HTML:

```
<textarea class="myTextarea">
Content
</textarea>
```

CSS:

```
.myTextarea
{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

[Example for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/VRp6m/).

[And an updated example for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/VRp6m/2/). (With margins added and a table for you to see it working in)

Also, do you have some code we can see? `textbox` isn't valid HTML so we have no idea what you're trying to use :)

Comment: setting to 100% will exceed the table's cell

Comment: So set it either to a lesser percentage or an explicit value :) (px, em, etc)

Comment: Whats with margin and padding=0 ? For me it seems to work (see my answer)

Comment: The default margins and padding should already be set to 0 unless it's inheriting then it should be explicitly set for the element.

Comment: setting less than 100% will not adjust correctly. if the window minimised/maximised will not resize correctly

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<td>
<textarea style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;" rows=1 cols=1>
    text!
</textarea>
</td>
```

in my tests, it worked.

Comment: setting width to 100% will exceed the table's cell

Comment: Does it exceed also with a margin and a padding set to "0"?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" width=100%"/>
```

However, there is overflow to the left I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 1):

`style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"` does not work?

Comment: setting width  to 100% will exceed the table's cell.

Answer (score 0):

set your "textbox" (whatever that is... do you mean `textarea` or an `input type="text"`?) to 100% `width` and `hight` and it's `margin` to 0 and set the `padding` of your table-cell to 0.

Comment: setting to 100% will exceed the table's cell